# Why javascript setInterval (updater) interact PHP fwrite function?

Tags: javascript, php, setinterval, fwrite

So yeah, how javascript can interact fwrite PHP function? This is weird..
Javascript code is

```
$('#updater').ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#updater').load(location.href + ' #updater');
    return false;
  },5000);
});
```

PHP Code

```
  $file2 = fopen("hits.log", "r");
  $visitors = fgets($file2, 1000);
  fclose($file2);

  $visitors = abs(intval($visitors)) + 1;

  $file21 = fopen("hits.log", 'w' );
  fwrite($file21, $visitors);
  fclose($file21);
```

I'm doing visitors hit counter, after javascript auto-updater runs, fwrite do his function: add +1 to file (visitors hits). Why this is happening? How to trick javascript that only visitors count, not javascript updates? P.S. Sorry for my english :/

Comment: You are doing a pageloads counter. If you want a visitors counter, you need to somehow track visitors - eg. set a cookie and don't count their pageloads again if the cookie is set.

Comment: Otherwise someone could just hold down the F5 key and flood your counter.

Comment: Ohh.. I will try what you said, thanks=)